# MongockTemplate bean in integration test

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongock

how to autowired MongockTemplate in SpringBootTest?
MongockTemplate does not autowired in @SpringBootTest
I try:

full exception:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ru.fabit.visor.config.dbmigrations.MongoDBChangelog003PerfIndexesTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.springdata.v3.decorator.impl.MongockTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

what i will need to do?

Comment: i use mongock-spring-v5,mongodb-springdata-v3-driver.
version 4.3.8

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.